# ProtractorJS testing if new LI element has been appended to UL

Tags: testing, protractor, e2e-testing

Have protractor filling out a field, clicking the save button, which then appends the info to the UL (creating a new `li` for each save).

I want to test if the number of `li` elements increased or if a new `li` was pushed.

Having a lot of trouble on this, thanks in adv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a relevant [`count()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) function:

```
var list = element.all(by.css('ul.items li'));

expect(list.count()).toBe(3);
```

Also, if you want to check the last element in `list`, get it using `last()`, for example:

```
expect(list.last().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly what I was trying to do, had trouble putting it together..